# Why is my tikz code not compiling in Overleaf

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, compiling, overleaf

I am writing a latex code for a research article. My experience with latex is limited but I know the basics.

My code looks like below. Inside the document, I am trying to include a tikz code for an image. (I created this code using matcha.io). However, it seems to be not compiling in overleaf. Can someone  point out what is the issue.

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
% The preceding line is only needed to identify funding in the first footnote. If that is unneeded, please comment it out.
\let\oldvec\vec
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{breqn}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[compact]{titlesec}
\titlespacing{\section}{10pt}{3pt}{3pt}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{interval}
\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amsmath,etoolbox}
\usepackage[ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\setlist{nolistsep,leftmargin=.6cm}
\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
    T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, bm, cite, epsfig, psfrag}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{cuted}
\usepackage{soul} %didn't have package _ojas
\usepackage[left=0.65in, right=0.65in, bottom=0.99in, top=0.66in]{geometry}
\usepackage{dblfloatfix}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{lipsum}%didn't have package _ojas
%\usepackage{ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{3cm}}
\usepackage[font=small]{caption}
\usepackage{epstopdf}   
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{supertabular,booktabs}
\usepackage{bbm}%didn't have package _ojas
\usepackage{multirow}
%\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\usepackage{subfigure}%didn't have package _ojas
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{pbox}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{tabu}   %didn't have package _ojas
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\def\PL{\mathrm{PL}}
\def\dB{\mathrm{dB}}

\usepackage{tikz}



\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[C]{Confidential}
\usepackage{bm}
%\linespread{2}
\newtoggle{conference}
%\toggletrue{conference} % Use for GC version -- also change documentclass above
\togglefalse{conference} % Use for arxiv version -- also change documentclass
\interdisplaylinepenalty=2500

\def\del{\partial}
\def\ds{\displaystyle}
\def\ts{\textstyle}
\def\nn{\no}
\def\binomial{\mathop{\mathrm{binomial}}}
\def\half{{\ts\frac{1}{2}}}
\def\Half{{\frac{1}{2}}}
\def\N{{\mathbb{N}}}
\def\Z{{\mathbb{Z}}}
\def\Q{{\mathbb{Q}}}
\def\R{{\mathbb{R}}}
\def\C{{\mathbb{C}}}
\def\argmin{\mathop{\mathrm{arg\,min}}}
\def\argmax{\mathop{\mathrm{arg\,max}}}
%\def\span{\mathop{\mathrm{span}}}
\def\diag{\mathop{\mathrm{diag}}}
\def\x{\times}
\def\limn{\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}}
\def\liminfn{\liminf_{n \rightarrow \infty}}
\def\limsupn{\limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty}}
\def\MID{\,|\,}
\def\MIDD{\,;\,}
\newcommand{\leqn}[1]{{\overset{\mathrm{(#1)}}{\leq}}}

\makeatletter
\newsavebox\myboxA
\newsavebox\myboxB
\newlength\mylenA
\newcommand*\xoverline[2][0.75]{%
    \sbox{\myboxA}{$\m@th#2$}%
    \setbox\myboxB\null% Phantom box
    \ht\myboxB=\ht\myboxA%
    \dp\myboxB=\dp\myboxA%
    \wd\myboxB=#1\wd\myboxA% Scale phantom
    \sbox\myboxB{$\m@th\overline{\copy\myboxB}$}%  Overlined phantom
    \setlength\mylenA{\the\wd\myboxA}%   calc width diff
    \addtolength\mylenA{-\the\wd\myboxB}%
    \ifdim\wd\myboxB<\wd\myboxA%
       \rlap{\hskip 0.5\mylenA\usebox\myboxB}{\usebox\myboxA}%
    \else
        \hskip -0.5\mylenA\rlap{\usebox\myboxA}{\hskip 0.5\mylenA\usebox\myboxB}%
    \fi}

\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
\newtheorem*{theorem*}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}
\newtheorem{assumption}{Assumption}
\newtheorem{claim}{Claim}
\def\qed{\mbox{} \hfill $\Box$}
\setlength{\unitlength}{1mm}

\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}




\begin{document}

\tikzset{every picture/.style={line width=0.75pt}} %set default line width to 0.75pt        

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.75pt,y=0.75pt,yscale=-1,xscale=1]
%uncomment if require: \path (0,353); %set diagram left start at 0, and has height of 353


%Shape: Rectangle [id:dp22457526275614637] 
\draw   (59.67,69.83) -- (92.5,69.83) -- (92.5,96.23) -- (59.67,96.23) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Rectangle [id:dp3289801767420759] 
\draw   (59.67,110.83) -- (92.5,110.83) -- (92.5,137.32) -- (59.67,137.32) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Rectangle [id:dp6068291618082182] 
\draw   (59.67,217.6) -- (92.5,217.6) -- (92.5,242.83) -- (59.67,242.83) -- cycle ;
%Straight Lines [id:da8811710099492369] 
\draw  [dash pattern={on 0.84pt off 2.51pt}]  (76.21,142.88) -- (76.74,213.84) ;

%Straight Lines [id:da33012444847161304] 
\draw    (93,125) -- (146.67,125.8) ;
\draw [shift={(148.67,125.83)}, rotate = 180.86] [color={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.75]    (10.93,-3.29) .. controls (6.95,-1.4) and (3.31,-0.3) .. (0,0) .. controls (3.31,0.3) and (6.95,1.4) .. (10.93,3.29)   ;
%Straight Lines [id:da34696364935690194] 
\draw    (92,230) -- (145.67,230.8) ;
\draw [shift={(147.67,230.83)}, rotate = 180.86] [color={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.75]    (10.93,-3.29) .. controls (6.95,-1.4) and (3.31,-0.3) .. (0,0) .. controls (3.31,0.3) and (6.95,1.4) .. (10.93,3.29)   ;
%Straight Lines [id:da6237546399599201] 
\draw    (93,83) -- (146.67,83.8) ;
\draw [shift={(148.67,83.83)}, rotate = 180.86] [color={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.75]    (10.93,-3.29) .. controls (6.95,-1.4) and (3.31,-0.3) .. (0,0) .. controls (3.31,0.3) and (6.95,1.4) .. (10.93,3.29)   ;
%Shape: Rectangle [id:dp7773352348344063] 
\draw   (157,52.83) -- (264.67,52.83) -- (264.67,252.83) -- (157,252.83) -- cycle ;
%Straight Lines [id:da6109689652801984] 
\draw    (266,71) -- (288,70.85) ;
\draw [shift={(290,70.83)}, rotate = 179.6] [color={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.75]    (10.93,-3.29) .. controls (6.95,-1.4) and (3.31,-0.3) .. (0,0) .. controls (3.31,0.3) and (6.95,1.4) .. (10.93,3.29)   ;
%Straight Lines [id:da047951388292807096] 
\draw    (266,93) -- (288,92.85) ;
\draw [shift={(290,92.83)}, rotate = 179.6] [color={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.75]    (10.93,-3.29) .. controls (6.95,-1.4) and (3.31,-0.3) .. (0,0) .. controls (3.31,0.3) and (6.95,1.4) .. (10.93,3.29)   ;
%Straight Lines [id:da34839111835378] 
\draw    (266,242) -- (288,241.85) ;
\draw [shift={(290,241.83)}, rotate = 179.6] [color={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.75]    (10.93,-3.29) .. controls (6.95,-1.4) and (3.31,-0.3) .. (0,0) .. controls (3.31,0.3) and (6.95,1.4) .. (10.93,3.29)   ;
%Straight Lines [id:da41060400275269915] 
\draw  [dash pattern={on 0.84pt off 2.51pt}]  (314,116.83) -- (314,127.83) -- (314,139.83) ;
%Shape: Circle [id:dp762871092762504] 
\draw   (474,80) .. controls (474,66.19) and (485.19,55) .. (499,55) .. controls (512.81,55) and (524,66.19) .. (524,80) .. controls (524,93.81) and (512.81,105) .. (499,105) .. controls (485.19,105) and (474,93.81) .. (474,80) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Circle [id:dp7600420357208382] 
\draw   (476,226) .. controls (476,212.19) and (487.19,201) .. (501,201) .. controls (514.81,201) and (526,212.19) .. (526,226) .. controls (526,239.81) and (514.81,251) .. (501,251) .. controls (487.19,251) and (476,239.81) .. (476,226) -- cycle ;
%Straight Lines [id:da8115776943587054] 
\draw    (325,64.83) -- (478.69,241.33) ;
\draw [shift={(480,242.83)}, rotate = 228.95] [color={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.75]    (10.93,-3.29) .. controls (6.95,-1.4) and (3.31,-0.3) .. (0,0) .. controls (3.31,0.3) and (6.95,1.4) .. (10.93,3.29)   ;
%Straight Lines [id:da2518078601190321] 
\draw    (326,94.83) -- (478.56,241.45) ;
\draw [shift={(480,242.83)}, rotate = 223.86] [color={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.75]    (10.93,-3.29) .. controls (6.95,-1.4) and (3.31,-0.3) .. (0,0) .. controls (3.31,0.3) and (6.95,1.4) .. (10.93,3.29)   ;
%Straight Lines [id:da22053870828697608] 
\draw    (328,242.83) -- (478,242.83) ;
\draw [shift={(480,242.83)}, rotate = 180] [color={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.75]    (10.93,-3.29) .. controls (6.95,-1.4) and (3.31,-0.3) .. (0,0) .. controls (3.31,0.3) and (6.95,1.4) .. (10.93,3.29)   ;
%Straight Lines [id:da7218928617499938] 
\draw    (326,94.83) -- (478.04,65.22) ;
\draw [shift={(480,64.83)}, rotate = 168.98] [color={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.75]    (10.93,-3.29) .. controls (6.95,-1.4) and (3.31,-0.3) .. (0,0) .. controls (3.31,0.3) and (6.95,1.4) .. (10.93,3.29)   ;
%Straight Lines [id:da4943900420018965] 
\draw    (325,64.83) -- (478,64.83) ;
\draw [shift={(480,64.83)}, rotate = 180] [color={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.75]    (10.93,-3.29) .. controls (6.95,-1.4) and (3.31,-0.3) .. (0,0) .. controls (3.31,0.3) and (6.95,1.4) .. (10.93,3.29)   ;
%Straight Lines [id:da8267005947489428] 
\draw    (328,242.83) -- (478.7,66.35) ;
\draw [shift={(480,64.83)}, rotate = 130.5] [color={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.75]    (10.93,-3.29) .. controls (6.95,-1.4) and (3.31,-0.3) .. (0,0) .. controls (3.31,0.3) and (6.95,1.4) .. (10.93,3.29)   ;
%Shape: Rectangle [id:dp7502542452092797] 
\draw   (304,52.83) -- (323,52.83) -- (323,252.83) -- (304,252.83) -- cycle ;
%Straight Lines [id:da4833542395072692] 
\draw  [dash pattern={on 0.84pt off 2.51pt}]  (314,186.83) -- (314,197.83) -- (313,223.83) ;
%Straight Lines [id:da6527936483027117] 
\draw    (326,154.83) -- (478.27,65.84) ;
\draw [shift={(480,64.83)}, rotate = 149.7] [color={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.75]    (10.93,-3.29) .. controls (6.95,-1.4) and (3.31,-0.3) .. (0,0) .. controls (3.31,0.3) and (6.95,1.4) .. (10.93,3.29)   ;
%Straight Lines [id:da20897174921677264] 
\draw    (326,154.83) -- (478.26,241.84) ;
\draw [shift={(480,242.83)}, rotate = 209.74] [color={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.75]    (10.93,-3.29) .. controls (6.95,-1.4) and (3.31,-0.3) .. (0,0) .. controls (3.31,0.3) and (6.95,1.4) .. (10.93,3.29)   ;

% Text Node
\draw (63,72.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [font=\small]  {$X_{t}^{a_{1}}$};
% Text Node
\draw (65,216.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [font=\small]  {$X_{t}^{a_{k}}$};
% Text Node
\draw (61.67,114.23) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [font=\small]  {$X_{t}^{a_{2}}$};
% Text Node
\draw (169,68.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [font=\LARGE]  {$\sum _{i=1}^{k} X_{t}^{a_{i}}$};
% Text Node
\draw (168,191) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]   [align=left] {{\scriptsize Hamming weight }\\{\scriptsize  \ \ \ computation}};
% Text Node
\draw (37,4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]   [align=left] {{\footnotesize Channel input}\\{\footnotesize  $\displaystyle \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ C_{in}$}};
% Text Node
\draw (309,62.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$0$};
% Text Node
\draw (309,87.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$1$};
% Text Node
\draw (310,232.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$k$};
% Text Node
\draw (493,66.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [font=\Large]  {$0$};
% Text Node
\draw (493,211.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [font=\Large]  {$1$};
% Text Node
\draw (453,7) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]   [align=left] {{\footnotesize Channel Output}\\{\footnotesize  $\displaystyle \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ Z_{t}$}};
% Text Node
\draw (49,281.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [font=\footnotesize]  {$active\ device\ set:\ \{a_{1} ,a_{2} ,\dotsc ,a_{k} \}$};
% Text Node
\draw (310,151.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$i$};
% Text Node
\draw (331.9,130.78) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [font=\scriptsize,rotate=-332.77]  {$p_{i}$};
% Text Node
\draw (333.36,161.54) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [font=\scriptsize,rotate=-29.2]  {$1-p_{i}$};
% Text Node
\draw (49,301.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [font=\scriptsize]  {$X_{t}^{a_{i}} \in \{0,1\}$};
% Text Node
\draw (353,279.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [font=\scriptsize]  {$p_{i} =1-e^{-\frac{\tau ^{2}}{i\sigma ^{2} +\sigma _{w}^{2}}}$};


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: It seems you load so many packages that the compilation exceeds overleaf's time limit for free accounts (1 min, see [here](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Why_do_I_keep_getting_the_compile_timeout_error_message%3F)). If I comment out most of the packages and their setting codes except for `tikz` and `amsmath`, your document compiles well.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Dou really need all this packages? Your preamble is big mess.

- In preamble you load almost all package twice or more time, even worse, some of them with different options! Clean-up it thoroughly!
- Some package, like `subfigure` and `filecontents` are obsolete
- Package `titlesec` doesn't work well with IEEEtran document class
- Package `caption` is not compatible with IEEEtran document class
- Don't use `enumitem` and `enumerate` package in the same document

**Edit (2):**
An attempt to clean-up of your document preamble considering aforementioned is in the following MWE. At this I wonder, if this article is intended to be published in some IEEE journal. If yes, than further cleaning is necessary in which you need to remove all redesigns of their desired format, i.e. remove package `geometry`, `fancyhdr`, `titlesec`, etc... In design of IEEEtran article consider instruction titlet which is available on [CTAN](https://ctan.org/pkg/ieeetran?lang=en).

Now it can be compiled without errors in (free account) Overleaf as well in my local installation of the MiKTeX with your image code. However, since it is awful (expected result when it is created by `matcha.io`), I redraw it from scratch with goal make it more clear, consistent and much shorter. Of course, further improving of image code and its design is still possible, but as is now it can serve as good starting point:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts              
\usepackage[hmargin=0.65in,vmargin={0.66in,0.99in}]{geometry}

\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[compact]{titlesec}
\titlespacing{\section}{10pt}{3pt}{3pt}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{interval}
\usepackage{booktabs, longtable, multirow, supertabular, tabularx}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
    \newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\hspace{0pt}\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
    \newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\hspace{0pt}\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
    \newcolumntype{L}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{3cm}}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{cite}
\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
    T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist{nolistsep,leftmargin=.6cm}
\usepackage{bbm, bm}
\usepackage{breqn}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsthm}
\usepackage{psfrag}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                fit,
                positioning,
                quotes}

\usepackage{cuted}
\usepackage{soul} 
\usepackage{pbox}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[C]{Confidential}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}[ht]
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
  node distance = 4mm and 8mm,
              > = Straight Barb,
     arr/.style = {very thick, loosely dotted, shorten <=2mm, shorten >=2mm},
every edge quotes/.append style = {auto, inner sep=2pt,
                                   font=\scriptsize, sloped, pos=0.7},
       N/.style = {draw, minimum size=1.3em, semithick},
FIT/.style args = {#1/#2}{fit=#2,
                          text width=#1,anchor=west,
                          inner ysep=0pt, outer sep=0pt,
                          draw},
every label/.append style = {inner ysep=1ex, align=center}
                        ]
\node (n1) [N]                  {$X_t^{a_1}$};
\node (n2) [N,below=of n1]      {$X_t^{a_2}$};
\node (n3) [N,below=12mm of n2] {$X_t^{a_k}$};
\draw[arr]  (n2) -- (n3);
%
\node[align=center, above=of n1] {Channel input\\$C_{\text{in}}$};
\node[align=center, below=of n3] {active device set:\\
                                  $\{a_1,a_2,\dotsc,a_k$\},\\
                                  $X_t^{a_i}\in\{0,1\}$};
%
\coordinate[right=of n1.north east] (aux1);    
\coordinate[right=of n3.south east] (aux2);
\node (f1) [FIT=5em/(aux1) (aux2), 
            label={[anchor=north]north:$\displaystyle\sum_i^k X_t^{a_i}$},
            label={[anchor=south]south:Hamming\\ weight\\ computation}
            ] {};
\foreach \i in {1,2,3}
    \draw[->]  (n\i) -- (n\i -| f1.west);             
%
\coordinate[right=of f1.north east] (aux3);
\coordinate[right=of f1.south east] (aux4);
\node (f2) [FIT=2em/(aux3) (aux4),
            label={[name=f2a,anchor=north]north:0},
            label={[name=f2b,anchor=north,yshift=-1em]north:1},
            label={[name=f2c]center:$i$},
            label={[name=f2d,anchor=south]south:$k$}
            ] {};
\draw[arr]  (f2b) -- (f2c) -- (f2d);
%
\node[align=center, below=of f2] 
    {$p_i=1-\exp\left(-\frac{\tau^2}{i\sigma^2 + \sigma_{\omega}^2}\right)$};
%
\foreach \i in {a,...,d}
    \draw[->]  (f2\i -| f1.east) -- (f2\i -| f2.west);
%
\node (c1)  [circle,draw, right=12mm of f2a -| f2.east] {0};
\node (c2)  [circle,draw, right=12mm of f2d -| f2.east] {1};
%
\node[align=center, above=of c1] {Channel ouput\\$Z_t$};
\foreach \i in {a,b,d}
{
    \draw[->] (f2\i -| f2.east) -- (c1);
    \draw[->] (f2\i -| f2.east) -- (c2);
}
    \draw[->] (f2c -| f2.east) to ["$p_i$"]     (c1);
    \draw[->] (f2c -| f2.east) to ["$1-p_i$" '] (c2);

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\lipsum[2-8]
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit (1):**
If you like to cover image with shadowed rectangle, than at end of image code add:

```
   \begin{tikzpicture}[
% existed image code
\draw[dashed, fill=gray!30, semitransparent]  % <--- new
    (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

By this resulted image will become as:

[image]

However, I guessing that you may like to have this rectangle as image background. In this case you need to add Ti*k*Z library `backgrounds`
and at the end of the image code:

```
\scoped[on background layer]
\draw[dashed, fill=gray!15] 
    (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);
```

Now the image will have the following looks:

[image]

One more possibilities, that images have gray background, but nodes are white. In this case you need add `fill=white` to all nodes style definition or rewrite image code as follows:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts              
\usepackage[hmargin=0.65in,vmargin={0.66in,0.99in}]{geometry}

\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsthm}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                backgrounds,
                fit,
                positioning,
                quotes}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
  node distance = 4mm and 8mm,
              > = Straight Barb,
     arr/.style = {very thick, loosely dotted, shorten <=2mm, shorten >=2mm},
every edge quotes/.append style = {auto, inner sep=2pt,
                                   font=\scriptsize, sloped, pos=0.7},
    base/.style = {draw, fill=white, semithick},
       C/.style = {circle, base},
       N/.style = {base, minimum size=1.3em},
FIT/.style args = {#1/#2}{fit=#2,
                          text width=#1,anchor=west,
                          inner ysep=0pt, outer sep=0pt,
                          base},
every label/.append style = {inner ysep=1ex, align=center}
                        ]
\node (n1) [N]                  {$X_t^{a_1}$};
\node (n2) [N,below=of n1]      {$X_t^{a_2}$};
\node (n3) [N,below=12mm of n2] {$X_t^{a_k}$};
\draw[arr]  (n2) -- (n3);
%
\node[align=center, above=of n1] {Channel input\\$C_{\text{in}}$};
\node[align=center, below=of n3] {active device set:\\
                                  $\{a_1,a_2,\dotsc,a_k$\},\\
                                  $X_t^{a_i}\in\{0,1\}$};
%
\coordinate[right=of n1.north east] (aux1);    
\coordinate[right=of n3.south east] (aux2);
\node (f1) [FIT=5em/(aux1) (aux2), 
            label={[anchor=north]north:$\displaystyle\sum_i^k X_t^{a_i}$},
            label={[anchor=south]south:Hamming\\ weight\\ computation}
            ] {};
\foreach \i in {1,2,3}
    \draw[->]  (n\i) -- (n\i -| f1.west);             
%
\coordinate[right=of f1.north east] (aux3);
\coordinate[right=of f1.south east] (aux4);
\node (f2) [FIT=2em/(aux3) (aux4),
            label={[name=f2a,anchor=north]north:0},
            label={[name=f2b,anchor=north,yshift=-1em]north:1},
            label={[name=f2c]center:$i$},
            label={[name=f2d,anchor=south]south:$k$}
            ] {};
\draw[arr]  (f2b) -- (f2c) -- (f2d);
%
\node[align=center, below=of f2] 
    {$p_i=1-\exp\left(-\frac{\tau^2}{i\sigma^2 + \sigma_{\omega}^2}\right)$};
%
\foreach \i in {a,...,d}
    \draw[->]  (f2\i -| f1.east) -- (f2\i -| f2.west);
%
\node (c1)  [C, right=12mm of f2a -| f2.east] {0};
\node (c2)  [C, right=12mm of f2d -| f2.east] {1};
%
\node[align=center, above=of c1] {Channel ouput\\$Z_t$};
\foreach \i in {a,b,d}
{
    \draw[->] (f2\i -| f2.east) -- (c1);
    \draw[->] (f2\i -| f2.east) -- (c2);
}
    \draw[->] (f2c -| f2.east) to ["$p_i$"]     (c1);
    \draw[->] (f2c -| f2.east) to ["$1-p_i$" '] (c2);
\scoped[on background layer]
\draw[dashed, fill=gray!15] 
    (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for this detailed answer. I changed my preamble based on your suggestions.
I have a additional question: On top of this image, I want to also draw a dashed rectangular border filled in grey color but transparent. It should cover everything other than the input and output blocks. Could you please tell me how to achieve that. I am not too familiar with tikz.

Comment: O the top? Try add at end of image code `\draw[dashed, fill=gray!30, semitransparent] 
    (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);`. This will cover image by gray and transparent color. Or you my prefer, that this will be on background of image?

Comment: @wanderer, see edited answer.

Comment: @wanderer, I edit answer again and ad more explanation and a bit more cleanup your document premable.